# copy documents from google drive to amzon-s3 programmatically by using java

Tags: amazon-s3, document, google-drive-api

I have download files from Google drive and save into my local system by using google drive api with java.My aim is to make a copy of documents from gdrive to amazon s3.

I can achieve this by download the Gdrive documents into my local directory and upload into amazon-s3 by using the s3Utility's `public void uploadToBucket(int userId, String bucketName, String fileName, File fileData)` method.
 Is there any direct way to achieve this? that is i want to reduce one step. i don't like to download documents into my local.Instead of this i would like to give the gdrive document's downloadurl into s3 method,it will need to save the document into s3. Is it possible? Any Suggestions? sorry the essay type of question

Answer (score 0):

You will need a server somewhere to run your code as both GDrive and Amazon S3 are closed services - you cannot add your own code to them.